# LDRB and STRB to rearrange characters and form a word

Tags: assembly, arm

Yes. This is for homework so please don't condemn me yet. I don't need an exact answer, but a direction to go.

I'm provided the beginning instructions that are pretty simple.

```
text        DCB 'K','D','S','E'
  LDR   R0, =text
```

I have to load these characters into memory, then rearrange them to create the word "desk" using pre-indexing addressing. Unfortunately, the fact that these are characters is completely stumping me. I've tried looking up multiple resources, and reading the books I'm provided and watching quite a few different videos and I'm just not wrapping my head around how to get started with this.

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? You know each character is a byte, right? Have you found the byte load and store instructions in the manual? Do you know how to use indirect addressing?

Comment: I wish I can use indirect addressing, but I was told it has to be preindexing addressing. and I know each character is a byte which is why I'm trying to use LDRB and not LDR. It's a dumb question, I know, but I'm not sure how to load and store character constants.

Comment: One easy way would be to load each byte into a different register and then OR them together with different shift amounts.  Then you can store them back with one `str` of the whole word (in this case, both an English word and an ARM 32-bit word).

Comment: And how would I load it as a character? (I'm really sorry. This is my third week and while I've been acing it so far we jumped in difficulty and are lacking material).

Would an example be like
     LDRB R1, [R0, #'k']?

Comment: Think of the characters occupying a space in memory, each in a subsequent memory location. 'text' points to the first location. You need to use an offset (or index) from text to obtain each character and place in another memory location in the order you wish...

Comment: `DCB` stands for Data Constant Byte (or declare byte, IDK, but the B is definitely byte).  I said "character" because this is ASCII, or the ASCII subset of UTF-8, so each byte is an entire character.

Comment: Thank you everyone. This really helped me wrap my head around this topic.

Comment: For CPU, after assembling, the character is just 8 bits (like `'K'` is assembled into 0100_1011 value, and that is stored in memory). It has no idea it was originally "character" in the source, and how it got assembled, at runtime it's just ordinary `0x4B` byte value, nothing else. What makes it "character" in final program is the logic provided by the code written by programmer, that that particular byte is loaded/used by routines which translate the ASCII code `0x4B` into output like graphical glyph on screen, having shape "K". But every information in computer is encoded in bits: 0/1 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since apparently ARM uses the term "preindexing" for simple register offset addressing as well, it's as simple as loading the 4 characters into 4 registers and then writing them out. Actually since `S` stays in the same place, you only need to move around 3. For example,

```
LDR   R0, =text
LDRB  R1, [R0, #0]
LDRB  R2, [R0, #1]
LDRB  R3, [R0, #3]
STRB  R1, [R0, #3]
STRB  R2, [R0, #0]
STRB  R3, [R0, #1]
```

Other literature calls the above "immediate offset" and only the write-back is "preindexed". For that case it's easy to rewrite the code as:

```
LDR   R0, =text
LDRB  R1, [R0, #0]!
LDRB  R2, [R0, #1]!
LDRB  R3, [R0, #2]!
STRB  R1, [R0, #0]!
STRB  R2, [R0, #-3]!
STRB  R3, [R0, #1]!
```